# Gitlab run docker inside docker

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab 9.3.3-ce.0 and gitlab runner with docker executor. I want to build images inside this docker-executor. How to do it?

I'm trying to connect to outer docker using this section inside `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`:

```
[runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "java:8"
    privileged = true
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/var/images", "/var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker", 
               "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock", 
               "/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker"]
    shm_size = 0
```

But when I try to execute inside docker `docker info` I get:

```
/usr/bin/docker: No such file or directory
```

But it should exist:

```
$ which docker
/usr/bin/docker
```

Comment: Probably /use/bin/docker is just a link. Try `ls -l /usr/bin/docker`

Comment: Have you tried docker in docker? https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that default installation of docker via apt-get is not visible inside docker itself, so separate standalone docker is installed and used.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the docker in docker service:

```
image: docker:latest

# When using dind, it's wise to use the overlayfs driver for
# improved performance. - THIS DOES NOT ALWAYS WORK!
variables:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay

services:
- docker:dind

before_script:
- docker info

build:
  stage: build
  script:
  - docker build -t my-docker-image .
  - docker run my-docker-image /script/to/run/tests
```

see https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor

Answer (score 0):

As the accepted response says, docker in docker is the solution.

However there are some sacrifices to make when using docker inside docker and there is, in my opinion, a better alternative: Kaniko project

You can use a kaniko image and easily build the docker image with it.
Here is some video I recorded with Gitlab and CI/CD using Kaniko. At the minute 30:45 https://youtu.be/Gb96kKN8BoI?t=1848 you can see the example.

[Gitlab also recommends Kaniko](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_kaniko.html)

Answer (score 0):

I leave working job recipe here to those who have troubles with GitLab docker dind mode, which became unstable recently:

```
build:
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - echo "{\"auths\":{\"$CI_REGISTRY\":{\"username\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_USER\",\"password\":\"$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD\"}}}" > /kaniko/.docker/config.json
    - /kaniko/executor --context $CI_PROJECT_DIR --dockerfile $CI_PROJECT_DIR/Dockerfile --destination $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```